# Magento TinyMce editor bug. Missing folders

Tags: magento, editor, tinymce

The tinymce wysiwyg editor used in the admin area appears to have a bug:

So I create a folder and upload a file to it (which appears to work just fine) then close the file upload dialogue. When I reopen the file upload box my folder and its contents have disappeared. If I check via FTP the folder is there. So I'm guessing it's perhaps a permissions issue? But I've chmod'd everything in the media wysiwyg folder to 777 and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas? Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it was all to do with a missing base table (core_directory_storage).

Changing to database and then synchronizing the media storage in System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Storage Configuration for Media worked. (Then changing back to File System).

This reply helped me:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219878/P15/#t326388

Thanks